# How can I unlock the hidden Navigators?

Tags: persona-4-arena

In Persona 4: Arena, there are six Navigators (essentially, announcer voice packs) that are available as optional paid DLC. In the Marketplace description for all six DLC items, however, it states that "skilled players can unlock this content by playing the game."

I know of the following **confirmed** methods so far:

> Teddie: Clear Story Mode completely
> Mitsuru: Complete 100% of one character's challenges
> Nanako: ???
> Aigis: ???
> Fuuka: ???
> Yosuke: ???

How can I unlock the remaining Navigators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, now that the dust has settled a bit and the community has had some time to investigate thoroughly, the closest thing that we have to 100% confirmation right now is that all of the "unknown" navigators from my original question [can be earned from Score Attack](http://mayonakamidnight.com/showthread.php?1715-Navigators-Announcers-requirements&p=57014&viewfull=1#post57014). (There are scattered reports of other methods, such as [mike's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80043/26052), but none that have been verifiably proven to work consistently that I'm aware of.)

Therefore, the closest thing I know of to an authoritative list at the moment is as such:

> Teddie: Clear Story Mode completely
> Mitsuru: Complete 100% of one character's challenges
> Nanako: Beat Score Attack mode with Yu, Elizabeth, Naoto, and Shadow Labrys
> Aigis: Beat Score Attack mode with Aigis, Labrys, and Mitsuru
> Fuuka: Beat Score Attack mode with Yukiko, Akihiko, and Kanji
> Yosuke: Beat Score Attack mode with Yosuke, Chie, and Teddie

For those who are absolutely dead-set to earn these unlocks by hand without resorting to spending money (or who wish to earn the achievements associated with them), note that you can slowly [lame out a win against the AI via liberal application of the pause button](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkhwJ-nXYPk). (Simply pause the game to see what move the opponent is performing, react appropriately, then repeat.)

I'll edit this answer if Atlus ever releases official unlock details.

Answer (score 4):

I got Yosuke after completing his arcade mode without a loss and his story mode (though I'm not sure if the latter is required).

Answer (score 3):

I only know how to unlock Fuuka, which is to beat the challenge mode. When they say skilled players, they **mean** skilled players. ):

Answer (score 0):

Get 'true ending' for all characters (story mode) for teddie, beat score attack for fuuka, i think you need to get 1.000 insta-kos in arcade/online :)

Comment: 1.000 ko's for yosuke